# Show DB In Array Using Foreach Loop

Tags: php, arrays, database, foreach

I'm trying to use foreach loop, for showing my DB but I always get error. What I want is to print each row and column. My code is like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT a.*, b.klasifikasi FROM kl_stre as b
        INNER JOIN data_latih as a
        ON a.id_stres = b.id_stres
        ORDER BY a.id_dl";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

foreach ($result as $dt_train => $row_dt_train):

foreach ($row_dt_train as $attr => $attr_dt_train):
echo $result[$row_dt_train][$attr_dt_trian]; // this line is the problem
endforeach;

endforeach;
```

the error I get is

> Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\knn\array_db.php on line 43

Would you mind explaining what is wrong with this code and how to solve this problem ?

Comment: wheres your query ?

Comment: It would help if you pointed out which line is 43... However I noticed a spelling mistake at the end of the echo line `$attr_dt_trian` should be `$attr_dt_train`

Comment: In my line 43 is my echo statement to call my array, give me some time to edit my post

Comment: my apologies @Eelke, I've made mistake but I've edited

Comment: can you post dump data

Comment: @RahulShrivastava, i can't get the dumb data because I get error Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function var_dumb()

Comment: if you are using laravel try dd() Or var_dump()

Comment: I'm sorry @RahulShrivastava, I'm not using laravel or another framework

Comment: @christ_tp its `var_dump()`  not `var_dupb()`;

Comment: I'm so sorry @RahulShrivastava, here the dump data :
array(9) { ["id_dl"]=> string(1) "1" ["nm_siswa"]=> string(2) "FS" ["sex"]=> string(2) "80" ["usia"]=> string(2) "12" ["kls"]=> string(1) "1" ["saudara"]=> string(1) "2" ["anak"]=> string(1) "2" ["id_stres"]=> string(1) "1" ["klasifikasi"]=> string(12) "Stres Ringan" }

Comment: @christ_tp i updated answer try it

Answer (score 0):

you need to first check your query

```
if (!$result) {
    die('query is not correct'.mysqli_error($conn));//$con is your database connection paste it after $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

after that fetch record  and simply remove `foreach` and try to use `while()` loop

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['your database field name'];
}
```

your code will be

```
$sql = "SELECT a.*, b.klasifikasi FROM kl_stre as b
        INNER JOIN data_latih as a
        ON a.id_stres = b.id_stres
        ORDER BY a.id_dl";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('query is not correct'.mysqli_error($conn));
}
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['your database field name'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @RahulShrivasta, it help me